# Javascript encoding for xml

Tags: javascript, xml, string, replace

I am trying to encode my inputs with javascript so they do not break my xml that i am creating. Right now I have this

```js
function encodeMe(myString) {
      myString.replace("&", "&amp");
      myString.replace("<", "&lt");
      myString.replace(">", "&gt");
      myString.replace("\"", "&apos");
      myString.replace("'", "&quot");
      return myString;
}
```

and for some reason the first 2 replaces are not properly working and are still breaking my xml

Comment: Use an external `.js` instead? Or CDATA blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Four things:

1. `replace` **returns** the updated string, so you have to use the return value.
2. When the first argument is a string, it only replaces teh first occurrence; to replace all of them, you have to give a regular expression with the `g` flag.
3. Character entities end with `;` (e.g., `&amp;`, not `&amp`).
4. `"` is `&quot;`, not `&apos;`; and `'` is `&apos;`, not `&quot;`

For example:

```
function encodeMe(myString) {
      mystring = myString.replace(/&/g, "&amp;");
      mystring = myString.replace(/</g, "&lt;");
      mystring = myString.replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
      mystring = myString.replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
      mystring = myString.replace(/'/g, "&apos;");
      return myString;
}
```

or of course, one long chained statment:

```
function encodeMe(myString) {
      mystring = myString.replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
                         .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
                         .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
                         .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
                         .replace(/'/g, "&apos;");
      return myString;
}
```

I'm also not 100% sure XML has `&apos;`. **HTML** does, but I'm not sure XML does.

Answer (score 1):

Missing a `;` -- though I think you have your last two characters switched around.

And you want those replaces to also have the global flag.

```
function encodeMe(myString) {
     var r = myString.replace("&", "&amp;")
       .replace("<", "&lt;")
       .replace(">", "&gt;")
       .replace("\"", "&apos;")
       .replace("'", "&quot;");

      return r
}
```

Comment: Good catch on the quot/apos thing.